# Error while calling AJAX request for forecast.io api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting following error when I call forecast api as an asynchronous call

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

I am setting content-type as

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
```

Any idea why I might be getting this error?

Comment: This is a common error, you can use `jsonp` or change server code to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSONP`, forecast.io [supports it](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2#options).

> callback=[callback]: Return the API response as JSONP. Please use
>   caution when using this, since exposing your API key to the public is
>   a security hazard and, if abused, will result in the revokation of
>   your API key. However, if developing a personal- or internal-use app,
>   this is a convenient method of doing so.